# PHP : send mail in localhost

Tags: php, email

I would like to send email through php code hosted locally.

```
<?php 
$email  = "myemail@local.com"; 
$titre   = "My subject"; 
$message = "Text message !"; 
mail($email, $titre, $message); 
?>
```

When I run this code, I get the following error :

```
Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\...
```

I went into the `php.ini` file and it seems to be already well configured.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

How can I fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: you can't send mail from localhost, configure some other smtp at localhost `eg : google,yahoo...`

Comment: "failed to connect to mailserver"... you have configured to PHP to connect to a mailserver at localhost, port 25. Have you installed such mailserver?

Comment: what is your running system ?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar — Not true! Any computer connected to a network can send email.

Comment: @Quentin from localhost port 25?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar — If you install an SMTP server and configure it to listen on that port - yes.

Comment: @Quentin Is there any way we can get the free SMTP server? How can se get the SMTP server?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar — There are plenty of free SMTP servers out there. I usually use Postfix. Using your service provider's server is likely a better idea though. Maintaining an SMTP server can be tricky (given spammers screwing up the ecosystem).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is configured to use `localhost:25` for the mail server.

The error message says that it can't connect to `localhost:25`.

Therefore you have two options:

1. Install / Properly configure an SMTP server on localhost port 25
2. Change the configuration to point to some other SMTP server that you *can* connect to

Comment: Not a very helpful answer.  You basically said if its not working then make it work or make another server work.

Comment: @mgrenier — As opposed to what other answer? A product recommendation would be off topic.

Comment: Contrary to @mgrenier 's comment, I found this to be probably the most basic, yet informative response online lol. "its broke".... "fix it" simple enough for me.

Comment: Your comments under OP were very helpful as well, probably worth putting in your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I spent hours on this. I used to not get errors but mails were never sent. Finally I found a solution and I would like to share it.

```
<?php
include 'nav.php';
/*
    Download PhpMailer from the following link:
    https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer (CLick on Download zip on the right side)
    Extract the PHPMailer-master folder into your xampp->htdocs folder
    Make changes in the following code and its done :-)

    You will receive the mail with the name Root User.
    To change the name, go to class.phpmailer.php file in your PHPMailer-master folder,
    And change the name here: 
    public $FromName = 'Root User';
*/
require("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); //or select the proper destination for this file if your page is in some   //other folder
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com"); 
ini_set("smtp_port","465"); //No further need to edit your configuration files.
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "trials.php@gmail.com"; //account with which you want to send mail. Or use this account. i dont care :-P
$mail->Password = "trials.php.php"; //this account's password.
$mail->Port = "465";
$mail->isSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$rec1="trials.php@gmail.com"; //receiver. email addresses to which u want to send the mail.
$mail->AddAddress($rec1);
$mail->Subject  = "Eventbook";
$mail->Body     = "Hello hi, testing";
$mail->WordWrap = 200;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent!.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo  //Fill in the document.location thing
'<script type="text/javascript">
                        if(confirm("Your mail has been sent"))
                        document.location = "/";
        </script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: No PHPMailerAutoload.php found

Comment: this is a good answer but what if I need the subject to be written with non-English letters? Because I tried to do this and I got an email with like `×ž×™×™×œ` letters.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to install a local mailserver in order to do this.
If you want to send it to external e-mail addresses, it might end up in unwanted e-mails or it may not arrive at all.

A good mailserver which I use (I use it on Linux, but it's also available for Windows) is Axigen:
http://www.axigen.com/mail-server/download/

You might need some experience with mailservers to install it, but once it works, you can do anything you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ini_set("SMTP","aspmx.l.google.com");
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: test@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
mail("email@domain.com","test subject","test body",$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send Emails without using any heavy libraries I have included my example here.

lightweight SMTP Email sender for PHP

https://github.com/Nerdtrix/EZMAIL

Tested in both environments production and development.

and most importantly emails will not go to spam unless your IP is blacklisted by the server.

cheers.