# Sending email via PHP from localhost

Tags: localhost, php

I am trying to send email using PHP’s `mail()`, but looks like I can't do that on localhost. Is there anything I can do to set up this to work on my Mac 10.6?

Comment: "looks like" ? mhh explain and describe the problem more specific.

Comment: you can connect to an external mail server such as gamil

Comment: Check this one out. for reference

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267423/php-send-mail-in-localhost

Comment: Just followed this link  http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/