# How can I create a simple program that it can send a text to a gmail address?

Tags: android, email

How can I create a simple program that it can send a text to a `gmail` address?
I want to create a simple program that it have a `EditText` and when I write some text in the `EditText` and I click on the `Button`, as the result the text be sent to a gmail address, for example to the `example@gmail.com`. I know how to create a `EditText` class but I do not know the operation post to the `gmail`. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, you can use Intent.`ACTION_SEND` to call an existing email client to send an Email.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"put_your_mail@gmail.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

For more details you visit [How to send Email in Android](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/) and

> http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-enabling-users-to-send-email-from-your-android-applications-the-easy-way--mobile-1686

Answer (score 1):

Standard way to do this is using the ACTION_SEND intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

If you want to send the mail in background without opening another app check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/2761055

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have information [how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610184/how-to-send-e-mail-from-server-with-android) in background with PHP file on your server.

But in my opinion, this method is deprecated.

Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application). This code will start new intent with email.