# what is the code for email notification to admin whenever someone posted to my blog

Tags: php, wordpress

i tried this code but nothing happens

```
add_action('comment_post', function() {
    $email = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
    wp_mail(
        $email,
        'New Comment Posted',
        'A new comment has been left on your blog.'
    );
});
```

Comment: visit codex.wordpress.org.

Comment: @jogesh_pi can you show how to set my wordpress site

Comment: change `$email` with your valid email address string and check. if it works then something is wrong with your `admin_email` validate the email address before executing the `wp_mail` code. and also check error_logs

Comment: @zzlalani nothing happens i checked my get_bloginfo('admin_email'); and its correct email address

Comment: is your server configured to send emails? just try this code. `mail('someemail@domain.com','sub','msg')` and check if it sends the email.

Comment: @zzlalani i only tested on my localserver. how to configure the server to send email? any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15267423/829533 http://stackoverflow.com/q/19132171/829533 
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/347696/sending-email-from-localhost-in-xampp-windows

Comment: thankz guys specially @zzlalani i'm gonna check these link